# Best way to create smooth archway?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, subdivision-surface, smooth

I'm trying to recreate a room interior and am modeling the basic structure. I'm having trouble modeling the arches in the interior, and have tried a view different approaches. The arch in the middle was created by joining a bezier curve to the mesh and extruding. The side archways were created using a boolean model. In both cases, the result was a very blocky style arch. [image]I've tried subdiving the bezier curve before extruding it from the mesh, but it still results in a blocky arch. I'm not sure what the best approach is to this problem. I've tried using loopcuts and a subdivide modifier, but I don't think that's the best way to model an interior... Any suggestions on how I can keep the rest of my interior flat but smooth out the archways?

Also here is the reference image I'm going for:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the shading, you can right click > *Shade Smooth*, then in the *Object Data panel > Normals* > enable the *Auto Smooth* option which will smooth only below the desired angle value:

[image]

If you are talking about the roundness of the edges you'll need to use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and bevel the edges to keep them sharp.

Comment: That does exactly what I want, thanks so much!